# Extending a SortedMap in Scala

Tags: scala, collections

I'm trying to extend a SortedMap in Scala, but I'm having some problems with SortedMapLike and canBuildFrom (the last one I can't even type it correctly). Here's some code; first the companion object:

```
object Timeline {
  ...
  def newBuilder[A]: Builder[(Long, A), Timeline[A]] = 
    new ListBuffer[(Long, A)] mapResult fromSeq

  def fromSeq[A](buf: Seq[(Long, A)]): Timeline[A] = 
    new Timeline(buf toMap)

  def empty[A] = Timeline[A](Map[Long, A]())
}
```

Then the class (yes, all my Timelines are from `Long` to `A`):

```
final class Timeline[A] private(t: Map[Long, A]) 
  extends SortedMap[Long, A] 
  with SortedMapLike[Long, A, Timeline[A]] {

  private[this] lazy val iMap = 
    TreeMap(t.toArray: _*)(Ordering.fromLessThan[Long](_ > _))

  override def newBuilder: Builder[(Long, A), Timeline[A]] = Timeline.newBuilder
  override def empty: Timeline[A] = Timeline.empty

  def -(key: Long) = Timeline(iMap - key)
  def get(key: Long) = iMap.get(key)
  def rangeImpl(from: Option[Long], until: Option[Long]) = 
    Timeline(iMap.rangeImpl(from, until))
  def iterator = iMap.iterator
  def ordering = iMap.ordering
}
```

I'm not sure all the above is the correct way to achieve this, but now comes the part I can't even type correctly:

```
implicit def canBuildFrom[A]: CanBuildFrom[Timeline[A], A, Timeline[A]] =
  new CanBuildFrom[Timeline[A], A, Timeline[A]] {
    def apply(): Builder[(Long, A), Timeline[A]] = newBuilder[A]
    def apply(from: Timeline[A]): Builder[(Long, A), Timeline[A]] = newBuilder[A]
  }
```

Comment: What is a `Timeline`? Is that just another name for `SortedMap[Long, A]`? Or do you have additional methods that relate `Timeline` and `Long`?

Comment: I have additional methods. I just put here the bare-bones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I was incorrectly typing `canBuildFrom`:

```
implicit def canBuildFrom[A]: CanBuildFrom[Timeline[A], (Long, A), Timeline[A]] = 
  new CanBuildFrom[Timeline[A], (Long, A), Timeline[A]] {
    def apply(): Builder[(Long, A), Timeline[A]] = newBuilder[A]
    def apply(from: Timeline[A]): Builder[(Long, A), Timeline[A]] = newBuilder[A]
  }
```

Comment: Without the error message, it would take us a long time to figure it out -- it's easy to overlook this error. However, the error message would probably be very familiar to us, and we'd figure it out easily. So... please, put the error messages in the question too.